# Send data from CustomTableView Class to its parent View Controller

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift-protocols

I have a View Controller "VCInicio", that has a TableView in his View, the Cells for that TableView are in a .xib format, the cells has a custom class called "CustomiseTableViewCell", inside there I have logic that gets and print a String (Phone Number) every time I click on a RadioButton, it prints its Phone Number, I'm able to print the value (From CustomiseTableViewCell Class) and see the value on console, but I need to send that value back to "VCInicio" so I can manipulate it from that Controller. I've seen lots of examples that suggest to use Protocols but I haven't been able to make them work.

[image: iPhone]

**EDIT**: Because of the structure I'm using, I can't work with **didSelectRowAt**, hence I'm working with the Selection of the Radio Button instead of the selection of the cell.

**What Fixed the Issue:**

"**CustomiseTableViewCellDelegate**" TableView Custom Class (Child Class)

```
//Protocol Implementation
protocol CustomiseTableViewCellDelegate {
    func onPhoneNumberClicked(_ cell: CustomiseTableViewCell, phoneNumber: String?)
}

class CustomiseTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var delegate: CustomiseTableViewCellDelegate?
    var phone: String?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        ...
     }

     //Here I get and send the phoneNumber 
     @objc func radioButtonTapped(_ radioButton: UIButton) {
        ...
        phone = itemLabel.text!
        self.delegate?.onPhoneNumberClicked(self, phoneNumber: phone!)
        ...
    }
}
```

"**VCInicio**" View Controller

```
class VCInicio: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CustomiseTableViewCellDelegate {
    func onPhoneNumberClicked(_ cell: CustomiseTableViewCell, phoneNumber: String?) {
        //Here I print the phoneNumber
        print("From VCInicio", phoneNumber)
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "phoneCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomiseTableViewCell
        cell.delegate = self

        ...
        //cell data config 
        ...

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: When ever you print the phone number. Why don't you use NotificationCenter.default.post(numberTapped, phoneNumber)
And then in the viewcontroller you can just observe that notification, and read the phone number and manipulate it.

Comment: Do you mind giving and Answer so I can try ? I've never work with NC before and tried a quick implementation a couple of hours ago and failed :(

Comment: Please share what you tried and what failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use custom protocols:

Assuming you have the numbers stored in some model in variable `phoneNumbers: [String]`

1. Make your VC table view delegate:

```swift
self.tableView.delegate = self
```

2. Extend ViewController to conform `UITableViewDelegate` protocol

```swift
class VCInicio: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

//...

}
```

3. Implement `func tableView(UITableView, didSelectRowAt: IndexPath)` and use selected cell phone value to manipulate it later

```swift
class VCInicio: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

//...

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selectedPhoneNumber = self.model.phoneNumbers[indexPath.row]
        // manipulate selectedPhoneNumber
    }

}
```

---

With protocols:

1. Define cell delegate and use it in the method for click

```swift
protocol CustomiseTableViewCellDelegate: class {
    func onPhoneNumberClicked(_ cell: CustomiseTableViewCell, phoneNumber: String?)
}

class CustomiseTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    weak var delegate: CustomiseTableViewCellDelegate?
    // ... rest of your cell class

   func onPhoneClicked() {
       // this is the function where you have code to print the number to console
      print(self.phoneNumberLabel.text)
      self.delegate?.onPhoneNumberClicked(self, self.phoneNumberLabel.text)
   }

}
```

2. In your `UITableViewDataSource` method for creating cells make `VCInicio` as cell's delegate

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   // assuming you have your cell here
   cell.delegate = self

   return cell
}
```

3. Make your VC conform to `CustomiseTableViewCellDelegate` protocol

```swift
class VCInicio: UIViewController, CustomiseTableViewCellDelegate {

//...

    override func onPhoneNumberClicked(_ cell: CustomiseTableViewCell, phoneNumber: String?) {
        // manipulate phoneNumber
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you @arkus for your reply. Because of the structure I'm using, I have the selection for the row disable, since I'm working with the selection of the Radio Button inside that Cell, not the selection of the cell, I can't implement this.

Comment: @Schavcovsky I've updated my answer with an example for custom protocol aka cell delegate.

Comment: Thank you @arkus I was able to implement step 1 and 3, for 2 I have already defined cell, so I'm not sure were to implement the step 2 **cell.delegate = self** since it fails when using between my declaration and return of the cell. Yet haven't been able to print from VCInicio the phoneNumber.

Comment: @Schavcovsky can you update your question with code for creating the cell?
What error it gives you when you put that line between `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(...)` and `return cell`?

Comment: I guess it was the position where I declared it, I put it just below the declaration of the **var cell = ...** and its working just fine now ! Thank you a lot ! Now I understand more how to use Protocols

Answer (score 0):

This code below is right now for an ImageView with a gesture recognizer. Which is targeted to the handleAvatarTap. Which is posting a global notification. Any ViewController or View can listen to notifications, and once the chosen one is posted the controller can act on this. 
In the example below is an example, passing the ImageView as an object for the notification.

```
// this is how I am creating a new notification name type
extension Notification.Name {
    static let didTapAvatar = Notification.Name("didTapAvatar")
}

// this would go within the cell where you are printing the number
     @objc func handleAvatarTap() {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .didTapAvatar, object: self)
    }

// This would go in to the view controller viewDidLoad
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleAvatarTap), name: .didTapAvatar, object: nil)


// This is the objc func within the view controller
 @objc fileprivate func handleAvatarTap(notification: NSNotification) {
        // checking the type of the posted notification object
        guard let avatarView = notification.object as? AvatarView else { return }
}
```